# move characters or shapes in console

Tags: c#

I am drawing rectangle to the console via code below, I could not find the way to move it left, right, top, bottom (when I call the draw function with different x,y it draws in shifted position, but I need to clear old lines).
By the way, I'm putting more than one rectangle to the console so I can't clear the console.

```
public void dragRectangle(int x, int y, int width,int height) {
            string s = "╔";
            string space = "";
            string temp = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                space += " ";
                s += "═";
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++)
                temp += " ";

            s += "╗" + "\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
                s += temp + "║" + space + "║" + "\n";

            s += temp + "╚";
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                s += "═";

            s += "╝" + "\n";

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.CursorTop = y;
            Console.CursorLeft = x;
            Console.Write(s);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
```

Comment: Since you are drawing a new rectangle every time... why is clearing the screen not an option?

Comment: for example i have inserted 5 rectangle , i will only move the last one with keyboard buttons other 4 will at their position

Comment: Re-draw all 5 rectangles, 4 remain where they are the 5th one moves?

Comment: @JohnG so you are suggesting that put string of all rectangles to a collection , clear screen , redraw first 4 with old location then draw new one with new location?

Comment: Yes, however because the code is using strings and spaces, the rectangles will not be clipped when they overlap. You will have to draw the rectangle character by character to get the rectangles to clip.

Comment: If your rectangles can overlap, then you'll have to redraw other rectangles in any case.

Answer (score 0):

The way the supplied code draws the rectangle, using strings and spaces the boxes will crop off anything to the left of the box and also underneath. In other words… when the boxes overlap, all the boxes below will not be visible inside the top box or to the left of the top box. This is because you are using strings with spaces, to draw the rectangle. Draw the rectangle using characters and not strings. The code below does use a string to print the top and bottom portions.

Below is a revision of the `dragRectangle` method showing what I described above. Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
public static void dragRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
  //set top corners
  string curCorner = "╔";
  Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
  Console.WriteLine(curCorner);
  curCorner = "╗"; ;
  Console.SetCursorPosition(x + width + 1, y);
  Console.WriteLine(curCorner);
  //set bottom corners
  curCorner = "╚";
  Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + height);
  Console.WriteLine(curCorner);
  curCorner = "╝";
  Console.SetCursorPosition(x + width + 1, y + height);
  Console.WriteLine(curCorner);
  // set top/bottom horizontal bar
  string horizontalBar = new string('═', width);
  Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 1, y);
  Console.WriteLine(horizontalBar);
  Console.SetCursorPosition(x + 1, y + height);
  Console.WriteLine(horizontalBar);
  // set left/right vertical bar
  string vertBar = "║";
  for (int i = 1; i < height; i++) {
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y + i);
    Console.WriteLine(vertBar);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(x + width + 1, y + i);
    Console.WriteLine(vertBar);
  }
  Console.ResetColor();
}
```